# run string as query in oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence, execute-immediate, ora-06512

i got a little problem in Oracle. I try to create a sequence for generating IDs in a table that already has data in it. I try to use the following anonymous block.

```
declare y varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 START WITH ' || (max(ID)+1) || ' INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20;' INTO y FROM TEST_TABLE;
  --dbms_output.put_line(y);
  execute immediate y;
end;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error report:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at line 5
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
```

If I execute the value of the y variable it works perfectly. I'm using SQL Developer as input interface and working on a 11g r2 Oracle server. I found similar codes where 'INCREMENT BY' parameter were script generated. Can someone explain my error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you `execute immediate`, the command you run should not have a semi-colon on the end; that is a command separator in SQL Developer (and [SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#autoId8), and other clients), not part of the SQL statement itself.

```
SELECT 'CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 START WITH '
    || (max(ID)+1) || ' INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20' INTO y FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

This is shown in the [examples for plain SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#autoId5). Just to help confuse you though, if you are using PL/SQL within the dynamic SQL, you do still need semi-colons appropriate to PL/SQL itself - though not the executing `/` you'd use to run it directly from a client. This is shown in [other examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#autoId6).